# Solution to Frozen Lock Screen: Linux Mint Cinnamon 18

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, gui, screen-lock

I'm a new linux user. I just installed Linux Mint Cinnamon 18 as my sole OS last weekend.

**The problem**
My lock screen is frozen at least once a day. I see a clock and a prompt to enter password. No keys work though. Best solution would be to prevent this at all.

**Things I've tried that didn't work**

- ALT-F1 and/or ALT-F2 to access terminal and enter password (the
  terminal doesn't even come up)
- xscreensaver

**System Info**

- ASUS Q502LA-BBI5T14 (It's on Amazon)
- Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit
- Cinnamon Version 3.0.7
- Linux Kernel 4.4.0-31-generic
- Intel i5-4210U @ 1.7GHz x 2
- Memory 7.7GB
- Graphics Card Intel Haswell-ULT INtegrated Graphics Controller

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize there was a different place for this. Flagged and sent

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem and tried different things suggested in 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1652489

Anyway, the solution for me was to install the package **Xscreensaver**. Its description reads "*install this package if you prefer xscreensaver to gnome-screensaver*" :-)

Now I can lock the screen and get bak in without any problems.

Comment: This worked for me on Debian stretch, to fix hangs when I would try to lock the screen while running xfce. Took just a `sudo apt-get install xscreensaver`

Comment: Xscreensaver also locks up when you click on lock screen now.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue on a my new build. Pressed control ALT backspace. Doing that brought me back to the login window, logged back in and all was good to go.

Answer (score -1):

I've used `CTRL+ALT+BackSpace` which is the key combination to terminate the X-server, this is the graphical driver for the user interface.